# Some Chain Rule Application

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
h(s):=D_xF(a+sb)c.
$$
**Question:** How should one interpret the RHS in
$$
h'_k(s)=D_x^2F_k(a+sb)(b,c)\,?
$$
**Thoughts:** I think $D_x^2F_k(a+sb)$ is the $k$-th row of the hessian matrix of $F$ evaluated at the point $a+sb$ and that $(b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector such that $(b,c)_i=b_ic_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Is this correct?

Comment: This is not possible: ${D_x}F\left( {a + sb} \right)c$. $a$ and $b$ have to be point or vector from ${\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Comment: @Frieder Indeed there was confusion between the points $a$ and $b$ in $D_xF(a+sb)$ and the endpoints of the interval $[a,b]$. I changed the interval of definition of $h$ to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. First note that $h_k(s) = (DF(a+bs)c)_k = (\underbrace{DF(a+bs)_{k,\cdot}}_{\hat=\text{ the $k$-th row}})c = DF_k(a+bs)c$ where $F = \pmatrix{F_1\\\vdots\\F_n}$ so $DF_k = (\nabla F_k)^T$ is a vector-valued function.

Then
$$h_k'(s) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds} DF_k(a+bs)c = \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{D_{x_i} DF_k(a+bs)c}_\text{outer deriv.} \cdot \underbrace{b_i}_{= D_{s_i} (a+bs)} = b^T D^2 F_k(a+bs) c = D^2 F_k(a+bs)[b,c]$$
Where the $[b,c]$ denotes application of the bilinear form $D^2 F_k(a+bs)$ (can be represented as a matrix) to the two vectors $b$ and $c$. This matrix looks like
$$(D^2 F_k(x))_{ij} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} F_k(x)$$